# Thin film resistors & power derating curve

Tags: resistors

please take a look at the pic,
what would happen if ambient temperature goes over 180C?
would it still be functioning as a resistor at 180C even it can't dissipate anything anymore?

[image]

EDIT:
OK I will answer my own question:
After staying at 180C for 8hours, the resistors are still alive & functional, but the resistance values have permanently changed since, they never go back to the original values even back to room temperature.

Comment: It won’t last as long, if you need this temp choose a better part. Read absolute max specs. High Reliability but still has Arrhenius effects.

Comment: Above that limit they manufacturer won't guarantee that the part works. Since you can likely solder at higher temperature than that it probably doesn't immediately burn up but it will eventually fail if too hot for too long

Answer (score 1):

If you go strictly by the datasheet, then no, you can't go there.  That derating curve is clearly designed with the notion that the resistor shouldn't operate above 155 C for extended periods of time.

So it's up to you to either find another resistor, or accept that you're gone off the rails as far as Panasonic is concerned, and it's up to you to figure out what the resistor actually does at elevated temperatures, and whether that behavior will be acceptable.